# How to maintain latest callback values when using React hooks with observables?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, preact

I am writing my own Preact/React de-bounce hook using Rx.js as follows:

```
export type Debouncer<T> = (value: T) => void;
export function useDebounceCallback<T>(callback: Debouncer<T>, timeout: number) {

  const subject = useSubject<T>();
  const ref = useRef(callback);

  // Is this ugly?
  ref.current = callback;

  useEffect(() => {

    const sub = subject
      .pipe(debounceTime(timeout))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        ref.current(value);
      });

    return () => sub.unsubscribe();

  }, []);

  return (value: T) => subject.next(value);
}
```

The above code has a dependency on `callback` function which is called when observable produces new value and thus should be part of the `useEffect` dependencies. But that causes a problem as observables are meant to be subscribed only once. The `callback` is created new each time a render cycle passes. And, at a user level, there is no guarantee that `callback` will be wrapped in `useCallback` hook.

**What is the right way to always pass latest `callback` value to the observable subscription function?**

> I am thinking about using `useRef` as above and then immediately updating the `ref.current` with `callback` value on each render cycle but I am afraid, I am breaking too may laws of hooks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of quick ideas - maybe someone else with give a more in-depth answer.

First, using `ref.callback` inside `useEffect` doesn't break the laws of the hooks as far as I can tell since unlike `callback`, `ref` is the same with each render. So generally your approach seems fine to me, with the exception of the `timeout` parameter which does seem to break the laws (but that's easily fixed by passing `timeout` to useEffect).

Second, one approach that I myself try to use in cases like this (not sure if it will work for you) is instead of creating a hook, create a function that returns a hook:

```
const getUseDebounceCallback = <T extends unknown>(
  callback: (value: T) => void,
  timeout: number,
) => {
  const subject = new Subject<T>();
  return () => { <the body of the hook> };
};
```

This way you can use `callback` and `timeout` anywhere in the hook without breaking any of the rules. It's a very clean approach, but it means that the user of the hook, instead of writing a component, would need to write a function that returns a component:

```
const getComponent = (...) => {
  const useDebounceCallback = getUseDebounceCallback(...)
  return (props: ...) => { <component body that uses useDebounceCallback> }
}
```

This does work great in some cases though, I'm curious if it would work in yours.

Comment: Some good points. I wonder if `getComponent` would end up creating new component function on each render pass! Where would `getComponent` be called?

Comment: Yes, `getComponent` would indeed create a new component each time it's called, so it shouldn't be run inside the body of another component. It's a bit hard to a general answer - it depends on how the state is managed. But one example is you could call `C = getComponent(...)` and `new BehaviorSubject(...)` at the same place, then map the state held by the behavior subject to some JSX that uses `C`, then turn the stream of JSX into the final component.